# How to get rid of white background between pages in ionic

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to develop an app and everything works smoothly on a browser, but when I test my app on an Android device (specifically an Android 5 device) I get a white background between pages.

The app loads correctly, I get the splash screen (a custom image I made), then I get the home page. Now when I click a button that gets me to another page (ie: gallery) I get a white background for like 4-5 seconds and then the page loads. It happens with every page in my app, going back and forth.

I've tried a lot of things, running `ionic cordova run android --prod --release` seems to change those 4-5 secs to only 1-2, but they are still there. Also, it is a simple app, I started a blank new one, added 3-4 pages and just a background image on every page so I can differentiate it from the white background.

How can I get rid of that white background?

Here's my app-routing.module.ts in case it helps:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'impresa',
    loadChildren: () => import('./impresa/impresa.module').then( m => m.ImpresaPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'farmacias',
    loadChildren: () => import('./farmacias/farmacias.module').then( m => m.FarmaciasPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'telefonos',
    loadChildren: () => import('./telefonos/telefonos.module').then( m => m.TelefonosPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profesionales',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profesionales/profesionales.module').then( m => m.ProfesionalesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'image-modal',
    loadChildren: () => import('./image-modal/image-modal.module').then( m => m.ImageModalPageModule)
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If you need to see any other files just ask me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are are you routing to other pages? share your code for routing.

Comment: Im new to ionic / angular so, if i understand correctly you are asking for the app-routing.module.ts? ill add it to the question..

Comment: The "blank" page appears every time i load a page, its like a "preload" page i guess?

Comment: Its a typo in my previous comment. I am asking how are you routing from one page to another? Are you using angular router?

Comment: Yes i think so, im using angular and also ionic creates the router module automatically, i haven't touched it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your global .scss (or equivalent if you're using another style system), add the rule:

```
--ion-background-color:#<whatever you want>
```

If you want to target it more specifically in each page's style, use:

```
ion-content {
    --ion-background-color:#<whatever you want>
}
```

You can get more advanced and use images as well.

```
ion-content{
--background: #000 url('path-to-image') no-repeat 
center center / cover;
}
```

Comment: Thats great, at least its not white! but can i, for example, set an image instead of a solid color? or get rid of that screen completely? i dont think i understand what that blank page is...

Comment: Added images to the answer for you. You can't remove it entirely, as far as I know, as it is part of the ionic wrapper for the pages.